# Troubles with Fetch and XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, fetch

So I'm doing an assignment for school and am having troubles using an API in java script. When I use XMLHttpRequest I receive the status code "0". After being frustrated from trying with XML I tried using fetch, I now get the error "Fetch failed loading: OPTIONS 'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect'"

To put it in context I have converted an image to base64 and need to parse that base64 as a parameter to face++ in order to do some face recognition stuff, should be cool when it works!

Here is the XML code:

```
function getInfo(base64) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect");
    request.setRequestHeader('api_key', 'my key');
    request.setRequestHeader('api_secret', 'my secret');
    request.setRequestHeader('image_base64', toString(base64));
    request.send(null);
    request.onload = function() {
        console.log(request.status());
    }
}
```

And here is the same thing attempted with fetch:

```
function getInfo(base64) {
    var url = "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect"
    var data = {
        "api_key":"my key",
        "api_secret":"my secret",
        "image_base64":toString(base64)
    }

    var params = {
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body:data,
        method:"POST"
    }

    fetch(url, params).then(data=>{return data.json()}).then(res=>{console.log(res.statusText)}).catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

I'm obviously missing something here and would really appreciate any help! Hope I've formatted this correctly.

Comment: Please read the error messages in the browser console carefully - surely there's mention of `CORS` or `access-control-allow-host` or something along those lines (the issue is, you can't do that because the server you are trying to use does not allow CORS)

Comment: @JaromandaX Nothing along those lines? Thats all the error says. If that is the case how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you could try removing the headers params. This error

> Fetch failed loading: OPTIONS

is because you are sending some header that is not recognized by the server, i would start there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now get the error "Fetch failed loading: POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect"." Any ideas?